# Arduino CLI Compiler "ino" and some basic sketches lead to compile errors

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

I am trying to compile a basic Ethernet/UDP-Sketch with the cli compiler ino.

I have the newest version downloaded from their github repo.

`ino init`
and then the content of src/sketch.ino:

```
#include <SPI.h>         // needed for Arduino versions later than 0018
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>         // UDP library from: bjoern@cs.stanford.edu 12/30/2008

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {  
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 2, 177);

unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming packet,
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "ack";       // a string to send back

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;


void setup() {
     // start the Ethernet and UDP:
      Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
      Udp.begin(localPort);

      Serial.begin(9600);

} [...]
```

and then `ino build`

lead to an error:

```
WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:192:0,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/SPI/SPI.h:15,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/Ethernet/utility/w5100.h:14,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/Ethernet/utility/socket.h:4,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:4:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:116:83: error: declaration of C function ‘StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, const char*)’ conflicts with
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:115:27: error: previous declaration ‘StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, const String&)’ here
```

[...]

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp: In member function ‘uint8_t WiFiClient::getFirstSocket()’:
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:177:12: error: ‘SOCK_NOT_AVAIL’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [.build/mega2560/WiFi/WiFiClient.o] Fehler 1
Make failed with code 2
```

It seems to be the same problem as https://github.com/amperka/ino/issues/55 but they told the issue is fixed...

(Ubuntu 13.10, 64bit)